# mongodb : using update() to update and get the updated data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update and get the updated data like we do { new : true } for findByIdAndUpdate in case we want updated data . How do we do that using update function.

```
 mBooking.update(updateDbParams.condition, updateDbParams.update, function(error, resultData) {
    if(error)
      res.json(mResponse.response(null, null, "something went wrong", null));
    else
       {
         console.log(resultData); 
       }
 });
```

so console.log returns;

```
    { ok: 1,
  nModified: 1,
  n: 1,
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1483945954 },
     t: 1 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate` with `new:true` option

```
mBooking.findOneAndUpdate(updateDbParams.condition, updateDbParams.update, {new:true}, function(error, resultData) {
    if(error)
      res.json(mResponse.response(null, null, "something went wrong", null));
    else
       {
         console.log(resultData); 
       }
 });
```

Comment: yup it worked well, whereas  findAndModify is not working. Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) of MongoDB. I am not very sure about the node driver equivalent of this.

> Modifies and returns a single document. By default, the returned
>   document does not include the modifications made on the update. To
>   return the document with the modifications made on the update, use the
>   new option. The findAndModify() method is a shell helper around the
>   findAndModify command.

Answer (score 0):

The mongoose update function does not return the updated document. This is shown [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html).

As it explains, mongoose's findByIdAndUpdate function with { new: true } is the best option. Also shows the lengthier version of findById -> save.